# How do I override the template file of a view so that it no longer displays links in my view, but only the plain text?

Tags: views, theming, entities

How do I override the template file of a view so that it no longer displays links in my view, but only the plain text?

This is a body field where the titles of the refenced entities are displayed as links. I would like to disable this for this view. I would like to do this via the template file for the view.

Comment: You generally wouldn't, as creating a link would be something managed in the view settings.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can not change it via the View. I use "unformated list" to display the content. The function you probably mean is only available in views when I use fields.

Comment: In that case, you're rendering entities, and you wouldn't alter a view template at all, you would instead edit the setting for the entity, which could possibly require editing a template, but again, usually done through the UI.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use the striptags filter of twig to strip the anchor tags.
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/striptags.html

For example: `{{ some_html|striptags('<a>') }}`

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But I use the view template "views-view-unformatted.html.twig" .

And when I try something like this {{row.content|striptags('<a>')}} I get the following error:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: strip_tags(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in strip_tags() (line 1120 of /home/bavramor/data/Webdesign/Webseiten/landwehrcie-backup-drupal9-160522/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php).

Comment: You need to pass string as a parameter. I guess `row.content` returns array.